# 7-Dimensional Curvature and Curl

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, cross-product

The cross product from linear algebra is most often used in conjunction with 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional vectors.  However, it is also said to work with 7-dimensional vectors, although this version appears to live a bit deeper in the sea of mathematical prerequisites.

In multivariable calculus, 2D-Curl and 3D-Curl are very much connected to the 2D cross product and 3D cross product, respectively.

Curvature, with respect to arclength, has a loosely similar geometry to Curl (both involve some measure of straightness or lack thereof), and also connects with the cross product $(k = \frac{\|S'(t)\ \times\ S''(t)\|}{\|S'(t)\|^3}$).

This raises the question, does the 7-dimensional version of the cross product lead to a 7D-Curl, 7D curvature, or 7-dimensional versions of any other topics in multivariable calculus tied to the cross product which don't exist in every dimension?

Comment: You should certainly be able to define a 7D curl in the analogous manner.

Answer (score 2):

There is brief discussion of 7 dimensional curl, and electromagnetism, in *The Mathematical Heritage of C F Gauss* By George M. Rassias

https://books.google.com/books?id=9RyV75spbW0C&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=%227+dimensional+curl%22&source=bl&ots=fALlzY9s-A&sig=fCE0jNTvCM1v0Q7YLBkoIxxqxkM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNnJzC7rreAhUJ5IMKHSM0BkUQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%227%20dimensional%20curl%22&f=false